# Where is the gtk+-quartz-3.0 package located? (Trying to compile webkitgtk)

Tags: compiling, gtk, gtk3, webkit

```
prompt:> cmake -DPORT=GTK -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -GNinja
CMake Warning:
  No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
  same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
  become a fatal error in future CMake releases.


-- The CMake build type is: RelWithDebInfo
-- Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-fdiagnostics-color=always
-- Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-fdiagnostics-color=always - Success
-- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-fdiagnostics-color=always
-- Performing Test CXX_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_-fdiagnostics-color=always - Success
-- Checking for module 'gtk+-quartz-3.0'
--   No package 'gtk+-quartz-3.0' found
-- Found the following ICU libraries:
--   data (required)
--   i18n (required)
--   uc (required)
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:452 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:622 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  Source/cmake/FindLibSoup.cmake:35 (pkg_check_modules)
  Source/cmake/OptionsGTK.cmake:30 (find_package)
  Source/cmake/WebKitCommon.cmake:56 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:169 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/webkitgtk-2.26.2/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/webkitgtk-2.26.2/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I have already installed `libgtk-3-dev` using the apt package manager.

I am trying to install citrix receiver using the deb package. However it requires additional packages:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of icaclient: 
icaclient depends on libwebkit-1.0-2 | libwebkitgtk-1.0-0; 
however: 
Package libwebkit-1.0-2 is not installed. 
Package libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 is not installed.
```

Which is why I installed webkit gtk source from the website `(https://webkitgtk.org/)`
Particularly this link: 
`https://webkitgtk.org/releases/webkitgtk-2.26.2.tar.xz`

Comment: I think that gtk quartz is/was an OSX specific library

Comment: It seems like it is, but how do I compile webkit gtk without it? I need it for citrix receiver installation. Specifically libwebgtk-3.0 
`dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of icaclient:
 icaclient depends on libwebkit-1.0-2 | libwebkitgtk-1.0-0; however:
  Package libwebkit-1.0-2 is not installed.
  Package libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 is not installed.
`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please write your question in more reproducible way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: You're missing libsoup. Run `sudo apt install libsoup2.4-dev`

It's a red herring. The script looks for quartz (which is mac-only) and uses it **only if available.**

Looking at

```
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:622 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  Source/cmake/FindLibSoup.cmake:35 (pkg_check_modules)
  Source/cmake/OptionsGTK.cmake:30 (find_package)
  Source/cmake/WebKitCommon.cmake:56 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:169 (include)
```

It looks like the script it actually failing on finding **libsoup**. You can install libsoup with `sudo apt install libsoup2.4-dev`

Also, welcome to AskUbuntu!